# how can i use RegExp to grap data from this site?

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

i want to grap data from this site using RegExp
http://www.islamqa.com/en/ref/20494
specially data in div with class="subject-container"

i tried this

```
/<div class="subject-container">(.*?)<\/div>\s*/is
```

but it gave me Invalid RegExp

why?

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regex.  If you tell us what language you're using, we can suggest simple and effective HTML parsing libraries.

Comment: You can go this route if you want a lifetime of pain and suffering :) Do not try to parse HTML with regex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside html code:

```
<div class="subject-container" >
```

possibly missed one space

```
/<div class="subject-container"\s*>(.*?)...
```